# How to find$\int{x\ln^{3}(x)}{dx}$ with change of the variable?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was hoping you could help me solve this with changing the variable. The integral is $$\int{x\ln^{3}(x)}{dx}$$ Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using such change of variables $x=e^t$ and integrating by parts we get
$$
\int{x(ln(x))^3}{dx}=\int e^{2t}t^3=\frac{1}{2}e^{2t}t^3-\frac{3}{4}e^{2t}t^2+\frac{3}{4}e^{2t}t-\frac{3}{8}e^{2t}
$$

Comment: But why $\int e^t2(t^3)$ ?? i mean why $e^2t$ if $x=e^t$

Comment: Because $x$ becomes $e^{t}$ and $dx$ becomes $e^{t}dt$, so that it makes $e^{2t}$

Comment: Oh yeah thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For $n+1\ne0,$

$$\int(\ln x)^m\cdot x^n\ dx=(\ln x)^m\int x^n\ dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d\ (\ln x)^m}{dx}\cdot\int x^n\ dx\right)dx$$

$$=\dfrac{(\ln x)^mx^{n+1}}{n+1}-\dfrac m{n+1}\int(\ln x)^{m-1}\cdot x^n\ dx$$

Do you observe the reduction of the power of $\ln x$?

Comment: yeah i get it thanks man